# Jquery Mobile - $(document).ready not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

So I have a listview in which each component wired to an on click function which looks like this:

```
function launchNewPage() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "newPage.html", { transition: "slide"} );
}
```

The problem I am encountering has to do with the next page.  The page shows up just fine, but none of the resources are loading.  When I inspect the page in firebug, none of the necessary JS files are loaded.  On top of this, it doesn't seem like the $(document).ready function is ever getting executed.  Does anyone have any insight as to what I am doing wrong?  Sorry, I am a bit new to JQ... Thanks in advance.

### Requested HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> 
    <title></title> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/JqueryMobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/theme.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/JQM-DatePicker.css" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JqueryMobile.js"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JQM-DatePicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/mockjax.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/soyutils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/fields.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JSDictionaryObject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/AddingForm.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="page" data-role="page" data-theme="x">
        <div class="ui-body-x" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1 class="ui-header-style" style="text-align:left; margin-left:10px;">Add New Record</h1>
            <div data-type="horizontal"  class="ui-btn-right ui-button-group"> 
                <a id="cancelButton" href="http://www.google.com" data-role="link"  data-ajax="false">Cancel</a>
                <a id="submitButton" form="f" class="ui-btn-up-x" onClick="javascript:return submitPressed();"data-role="button" data-icon="" data-ajax="false">Submit</a> 
            </div>              
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="x">

            <form  id="f" src="#"></form>       
        </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

Comment: What is in the $(document).ready function on the second page, and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: There is another function that fires an ajax request to get the UI components for a form.

Comment: In firebug, I can't see that page's associated JS files or anything.  I don't think they are being loaded...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot start the jQuery mobile with `$(document).ready()` you should started like this:

try to work with this in the first HTML

```
$("div[data-role*='page']").live('pageshow', function(event, ui) { 
    document.location.href="newPage.html";
});
```

Comment: So this takes the place of the $(document).ready() function on the new page?

Comment: now, do you have to do it on both pages?  or just the new one that I am pushing over to?

Comment: That didn't do the trick.  It loaded the first page fine, but not the second one.

Comment: in both, remember, in the first you're going to do the redirection and in the second, in when you add the code in of the new html

Comment: maybe if you put the html of the second page i can see the problem

Comment: Right, but in the second, it doesn't even look like any of the other documents load.  For example, there is a JS file that should load, but that is not showing up in firebug...

Comment: Which part of the HTML did you want to see?  I have a div with the data-role of page if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: The Second HTML that you trying to load

Comment: Is "newPage.html" the HTML for the page that I want to navigate too eventually?

Comment: So that did the trick, but I added that line to my, launchNewPage() function not the one you posted above.  However, I am not sure if this is going to cause problems down the road.  It also doesn't do the nice push navigation transition.

Comment: I am going to mark this as correct for now, but I feel like it is a hack and not the real way to handle the page transitions.  If anyone has a better mechanism for this, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

Geoff, if you are using the Beta 3 version of the JQM framework, [read this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/events.html).  It will help shed light on the DOM and $(document).ready().  You may want to consider the "pagecreate" and "pagebeforecreate" events.  They are delineated in the doc referenced in the above link.

Comment: This too is helpful for understanding why.  Thanks for that.